# Setting grpc metadata in http request

Tags: rest, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am trying to create REST endpoints for an existing gRPC service using grpc-gateway. The gRPC service makes use of "metadata" passed in grpc calls to authenticate.
How do I set the metadata in my REST calls?

I have tried passing metadata key value pairs in the headers. But it did not set the metadata in context.

Comment: What library are you using to create and send out the REST reqs?

Answer (score 9):

The trick here is using a custom *incoming header matcher*. You can see in the source code or grpc-gatway, that there is a [WithIncomingHeaderMatcher](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/078fa178386eb47a74d194114fddefdf4ac30264/runtime/mux.go#L68-L72) that transforms incoming HTTP headers into metadata passed into the context (used later on by gRPC server handlers). By default it supports a set of so-called [permanent HTTP headers](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/078fa178386eb47a74d194114fddefdf4ac30264/runtime/context.go#L183-L206) which are passed as they are (so eg. `Authorization` header will come up as `Authorization` in the context), or you need to prefix your custom headers with a specific prefix, [Grpc-Metadata-](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/078fa178386eb47a74d194114fddefdf4ac30264/runtime/context.go#L22), see [its usage here](https://github.com/shipwallet/service-cos/blob/bde93d31b3cff93627cb038658d31f514fe7bf88/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime/mux.go#L57-L58). In this case, `Grpc-Metadata-Your-Name` HTTP header will come up as `Your-Name` field in the metadata.

Again, if this is too problematic for you and you with to be able to pass eg. `X-User-Id` or any custom formatted headers into your app, you need to set up a custom header matcher. I would recommend to handle your headers explicitly and then fallback onto the default one (works great if you then update your dependencies and some new `permanentHTTPHeader` is added:

```
    func headerMatcher(header string) (string, bool) {
        if header == "X-User-Id" {
            return "x-user-id", true
        }
        return runtime.DefaultHeaderMatcher(header)
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Grpc-Metadata-` This is important if we are using `DefautHeaderMatcher` Thanks @slomek